# swift closing a vc controller from within a FIREBASE_REF block

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I'm just looking for assistance in closing a createuser vc and returning to the previous initial vc if a user alreadyexists in firebase.

I currently have :

```
// Attempt to create a new user.  (authData = dictionary).
        FIREBASE_REF.createUser(email, password: password, withValueCompletionBlock: { (error, authData) in

// If there was no error then
            if error == nil {
// Authorise the new user into the application.  (authData = object).
                FIREBASE_REF.authUser(email, password: password, withCompletionBlock: { ( error, authData) in

                    if error == nil {
// Store the user id into the device.
                        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue(authData.uid, forKey: "uid")
// Stop the activity indicator.
                        self.activityInd.stopAnimating()
// Close the create user screen.
                        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
                    }
                    else
                    {
// Stop the activity indicator.
                        self.activityInd.stopAnimating()

                        print(error)

                   }
                })
            }
            else

// USER ACCOUNT ALREADY EXISTS \\
            {
// Stop the activity indicator.
                self.activityInd.stopAnimating()

// Display an error message.
                let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "USER DUPLICATION ERROR", message:
                    "user account already exists, login as normal", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
                alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default,handler: nil))
                self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

// Close the create user screen.
                self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

            }
      })
```

When the user creates a new account the self.dismissViewController works perfectly fine and returns to the initial vc and then loads the homepage.  However, when there is already an existing user the self.dismissViewController doesn't do anything.  If anyone can shed some light on this it would be much appreciated.

Also, if anyone can advise on how to ensure that the alert message stays on screen until the user selects dismiss before closing the vc that would be helpful too.

Thanks

Comment: I've narrowed it down, when I comment out the alert message, it closes the screen and returns as it should.  Obviously the alert message is causing the issue, if any can advise me on why this is causing the issue I would appreciate it.  I suspect that once the alert has been called, it is no longer continuing in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, if anyone is interested heres how I got round the issue:

```
// USER ACCOUNT ALREADY EXISTS \\
            {
// Stop the activity indicator.
                self.activityInd.stopAnimating()

// Display an error message.
                let refreshAlert = UIAlertController(title: "USER DUPLICATION ERROR", message: "user account already exists, login as normal.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

                refreshAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: .Default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
// Close the create user screen.
                    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
                }))

                self.presentViewController(refreshAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
      })
```